# Loosen heatsink screws not coming out of the socket plate

Tags: central-processing-unit, socket

I recently bought a dual CPU HP z640 off ebay. I got better xeons to replace the ones that came with the workstation, so I took out the daughterboard, unscrewed the screws (always in diagonally fashion) and the heatsink came out. 30 seconds. Piece of cake.

Then I moved on to the motherboard to "rinse and repeat" the procedure. But this time it didn't work. The screws are not coming out of the socket plate, eventhough they are completely loose. If I keep unscrewing I can hear a "tac" sound every turn, but none of the four total screws comes out. The hetskink feels like welded to the CPU, but I discarded the option of cemented thermal paste by pouring (lots) of isopropyl alcohol 3 or 4 times. By the way, you can't see any screws in the backplate either, so no option there.

I also tried unscrewing and gently pulling out the screw at the same time, but again, none of them worked. I can't remove the heatsink and I'm totally out of ideas.

So, my question is, how to get them our without damaging the mobo/socket?

Comment: I wonder why somebody downvoted this question. Before posting, I was using a lot of google-fu to no avail. And, language aside, I believe it's pretty clear. I can't evaluate how useful it is, because I do not know how rare is the situation itself. I doubt I'm the first person with this problem, though.